# Webpage is not mobile friendly, not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My first website is not mobile responsive. I have included row's and col-xs, col-md, col-lg but it is not mobile friendly still. What am I doing wrong. Please help.

My website page: http://www.kiljakandweb.com/

My **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>KILJAK & WEB</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.3/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-Wrgq82RsEean5tP3NK3zWAemiNEXofJsTwTyHmNb/iL3dP/sZJ4+7sOld1uqYJtE" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
        <meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="mstile-144x144.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="mstile-70x70.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="mstile-150x150.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="mstile-310x150.png" />
        <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="mstile-310x310.png" />

    </head>
    <body>


        <!-- Header -->
         <header id="top" class="header">
            <svg width="0" height="0">
                <defs>
                    <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                        <path d="MO, 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100, 0% 80%"/>
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>
             </svg>
             <div class="menu" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                 <div class="bar1"></div>
                 <div class="bar2"></div>
                 <div class="bar3"></div> 
             </div>

             <div class="text-vertical-center">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
             <h1>I CODE. IT'S WHAT I DO.</h1>


                 </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             <div class="arrow bounce"></div>
        </header>

        <!-- About -->
         <section id="about" class="about">
             <div class="container">

                 <div class="row aboutme">
                     <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                         <p>Decent portfolio is the perfect way to show off. This website features some brilliant projects from a London based full-stack Web Developer. Bears are for testing purposes only.</p>

                         <p class="russiantext">На самом деле, медведи тут не при чём. Это никак меня не характеризует, но история с их участием имеет место быть, поэтому пускай будут для настроения и атмосферы. </p>
                     </div>
                 </div>

            <!-- /.row -->
             </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
        </section>



<style>
#googleMap {
    width: 100%; /* Span the entire width of the screen */
    height: 400px; /* Set the height to 400 pixels */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%); /* Change the color of the map to black and white * /
}
</style>

<div id="googleMap"></div>

<!-- Add Google Maps -->
 <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyCJw0QfJXXleECtFD5031OMG75lZMiC6dY
'></script>
<script>
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5257, -0.0774);

function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:myCenter,
zoom:12,
scrollwheel:false,
draggable:false,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position:myCenter,
});

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>


<footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
                    <h4><strong>KILJAK & WEB</strong>
                    </h4>
                    <p>Ace Hotel Shoreditch
                        <br>London, UK E1 6JQ</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> (44) 7568599454</li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i> <a href="mailto:edgar.kiljak@kiljakandweb.com">edgar.kiljak@kiljakandweb.com</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr class="small">
                    <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; KILJAK & WEB 2016</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a id="to-top" href="#top" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-fw fa-1x"></i></a>
    </footer>

    <script>

        function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}

    </script>          


  </body>
</html>
```

My **CSS**:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.menu {
    display:inline-block !important;
    cursor: pointer; 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 45px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}


.text-vertical-center {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.text-vertical-center h1 {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-weight: 150;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}


.btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;    
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-default {
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  color: #42DCA3;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #42DCA3;
}

.header {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    clip-path: url(#myClip);

    -webkit-clip-path: url(#myClip);
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    0 0, /* left top */
    100% 0, /* right top */ 
    100% 100%, /* right bottom */
    0% 85% /* left bottom */
  );    

}

#top {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 50px !important;
    line-height: 15px;
}

.about {


    padding: 200px 0;
    background-color: lightgray;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    background-image: url('../images/Untitled-20.png');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;



}

.aboutme {
    border: solid;
    border-width: thick;
    padding: 60px 20px 60px 20px;
    margin: 100px;
    border-color: #23527C;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 29px !important;
    line-height: 49px;

}



.russiantext {
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 29px !important;
}

.conactme {
    padding: 100px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #eae8e8;
    padding: 100px 0;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px !important;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. The idea is to post a [mcve] and not just dump your page on our unsuspecting heads to eyeball debug. Bears and all. Cut your issues into small pieces and ask well defined questions or see your question closed as off topic as too broad.
Please note the `<>` button in the editor. It will give you a place to put working code to the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason for the site not being responsive, and a starting point for solving your problem, is that you appear to have applied the same column widths to all screen sizes.

For `.col-*` classes, different infixes represent how the column should look like on different screen sizes:

- `xs-` represents (more or less) smartphones,
- `sm-` represents tablets,
- `md-` represents non-widescreen computer monitors,
- `lg-` represents widescreen computer monitors.

So, when you set classes like `col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10` then you're basically telling Bootstrap: *"please make this 10/12th wide on every screen size"* - which is the opposite of responsive design.

You should use different values for different infixes, for example `col-sm-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3`, which tells Bootstrap *"make this full width on smartphones, half the width on tablets, 1/3rd on small PC screens and 1/4th on widescreens"*.